# Vue Relative Paths with the CLI Service

Tags: vue.js

Running into a problem which is surely related to Webpack.

Tried to do the most basic of services as a smoke test (start small) in a Vue app created by the CLI.

Versions:
Vue CLI: 3.11.0
vue 2.6.10
@vue/CLI-Service 4.0.5

I created a folder called `shared` inside the `src` folder of my project. The `HelloWorld.vue` file is in the `components` folder. In that file, I imported a data service which I placed inside `shared` and attempted to use it in the `Created` event of the HelloWorld component:

```
<script>
    import { dataService } from "../shared";

    export default {
      name: "HelloWorld",
      props: {
        msg: String
      },
      created() {
        dataService.addWebSite();
      }
    };
</script>
```

The data service is very simple and just meant to hit an API (`data.service.js`):

```
import *  as axios from 'axios';

const addWebSite = function () {

    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://localhost:44362/WebSites/CreateWebSite',
        data: {
            name: "Pluralsight",
            url: "http://Pluralsight.com"
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        var discard = response.data;
        return discard;
    });
};

export const dataService = {
    addWebSite: addWebSite
};
```

When I execute `npm run serve`, I see the following error message:

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                              6:13:39 PM
This relative module was not found:

- ../shared in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

I'm guessing this is some kind of Webpack relative path thing, but am at a loss and have not been able to solve it using Google.

The `vue.config.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map',
    }
};
```

And I have tried adding a `publicPath` property of both './' and '/' to that exported object.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to import from a folder instead of file, like this

```
import { dataService } from "../shared";
```

it implies that you actually want to import from `"../shared/index.(any_supported_extension)"`. But since your file is actually named `data.service.js` you will have to change your import to

```
import { dataService } from "../shared/data.service.js";
```

Comment: Of course. Thanks. I did actually try that earlier, but this time it worked. And it makes complete sense as the example I was going off had an index file which was exporting things from every service in the folder. Thanks.